# Smooth Motion with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm having trouble getting smooth and fluid motion with java Swing. Using this code, which involves using a BufferedImage to draw graphics to before applying it to the panel, gives me results with shaky motion and stuttering. How can I fix this?

```java
public class SmoothMotion extends JPanel {

    public static final int size = 800;
    public static int pos = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new SmoothMotion();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Smooth As");
        frame.setSize(size, size);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Timer timer = new Timer(17, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SmoothMotion.updateItems();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void updateItems() {
        pos += 4;
        pos = pos > 750 ? 0 : pos;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(pos > 375 ? 750 - pos : pos, 100, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)`
2. there is no need for the BufferedImage. Swing is double buffered by default. Just invoke `super.paintComponent(graphics)` first to clear the background and then do your custom painting.
3. the painting method should NOT change properties of the class. You should have a method like `updatePos(…)` to update the position.
4. The ActionLIstener would invoke the `updatePos()` which would then invoke `repaint()`.

See: [get width and height of JPanel outside of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028090/get-width-and-height-of-jpanel-outside-of-the-class/54028681#54028681) for an example that demonstrates many of the above suggestions.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code to match what you suggested. I also changed the timer interval to be closer to a 60fps refresh rate and increased the position increment accordingly. I still seem to be getting stuttering, though. Is there anything else I can do to get smoother motion? I put the modified code in my original post.

Comment: Don't think you can do any better using Swing. Check out: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34090/java2d-game-flickering for some reading material.