# Java moving an object (a simple machine simulator)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, command

I am working on a dusk cleaner simulator on Java, in this case the shape of the cleaner is a circular ball.

The program is quite simple, the user puts in the width and length of the "room" and coordinates x and y.

What I want to **do** and **cannot** is create a series of commands, each represented by a character. There are three commands that I want to imnplement:

**1. char 'A' = Move forward 1 meter**

**2. char 'L' = Turn left 90 degrees**

**3. R Turn right 90 degrees**

Example of user input ***AALA***, in this case the expected output is that the machine moves 2 meters and then turns left 90 degrees and then moves 1 meter again. Hope I am clear.

As you can see in the code, I have tried to create an array of chars but I dont know what the next step should be...

The code:

```
public class Cleaner extends JPanel {
    /* int lx = 1, ly = 1;
    int x = 200, y = 250;
    
    */
    int x, y;
    int width = 52, height = 50; // width and height of the "dust sucker"
    int lx , ly;


    // an array of chars
    char[] charArray ={ 'A', 'L', 'R'};     
    
    java.util.Timer move; // making the instance of Timer class from the util package
    static JFrame frame;
     
    Cleaner()
    {
        
        frame = new JFrame ("Cleaner started!"); // passing attributes to our fame
        frame.setSize (400, 400); // setting size of the starting window
        frame.setVisible (true);
        
        setForeground(Color.black); // setting color
        
        move = new java.util.Timer();
        
        move.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
        {
        
            
            public void run() 
            {
                if(x<0)
                    lx = 1;
                if(x>=getWidth()-45)
                    lx = -1; // -1 sets boundry for the dusk sucker
                if(y<0)
                    ly = 1;
                if(y>=getHeight()-45)
                    ly = -1; // -1 sets boundry for the dusk sucker
                
                x+=lx; // to make the machine move
                y+=ly;
                
                repaint();
            }
            
        }, 0, 5// speed of the machine
                );
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
    }
    
    public void paint (Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        // lx value
        
        String lxValue = 
                 JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter lx" );
        // ly value
        String lyValue =
                  JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter ly" );
        
        String xValue = 
                 JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter x value" );
        // ly value
        String yValue =
                  JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Enter y value" );


         // convert String inputs to int values 
          int firstInput = Integer.parseInt( lxValue ); 
          int secondInput = Integer.parseInt( lyValue );
          int thirdInput = Integer.parseInt( xValue ); 
          int forthInput = Integer.parseInt( yValue );
    
       
             Cleaner cleaner = new Cleaner();
             
                frame.add(cleaner);
          cleaner.lx = firstInput;
          cleaner.ly = secondInput;
          cleaner.x = thirdInput;
          cleaner.y = forthInput;       
        
    }
    
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some basics:

1. override `paintComponent()`, not paint() when doing custom painting.
2. use a `Swing Timer` for animation. All updates to Swing components need to be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

> in this case the shape of the cleaner is a circular ball.

So you need to create a class to represent the ball. It will have basic properties like:

1. size
2. location
3. direction of movement.
4. speed of movement.

You will then need to create methods to change the properties. Maybe:

1. move() - move in the current direction at the current speed
2. turnRight() - adjust direction
3. turnLeft() - adjust direction

Then you can create an ArrayList to store the moves and a Swing Timer to execute the moves.

Whenever the Timer fires you remove the command from the ArrayList and execute the command. By invoking one of the above 3 methods.

Check out: [get width and height of JPanel outside of the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028090/get-width-and-height-of-jpanel-outside-of-the-class/54028681#54028681) for an example that is similiar (not exact) to what you want. It demonstrates the concept if creating an object with the properties needed to control its motion.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but is it possible for you to give me code example?

Comment: @JanAdam, I did. No it is not exactly what you need, but it is a start. We are not here to write the application for you, only point you in the right direction.