# Drawing objects from another class to the same JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

my code runs, but the stone is not seen on top of the board [image: this is what my output look like when I run my code]

can anyone help pls!! my goal is to get stones on the board [ like the game mancala]

Comment: You're using a flow layout, and you're adding your stone to the flow layout. It doesn't have a preferred/min/max size so the content pane is giving it 0 space.

Comment: @matt so how do i give it space?

Comment: @matt a final int space because I want the stones to always be the same size

Comment: For starters you cannot use a FlowLayout. It will not stack components. You could use a JLayeredPane if you want to stack components.

Comment: The [JLayeredPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) has a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: @matt cool ill check it out, thx

Comment: Typically you would draw all the shapes on a single panel. This will allow you to easily stack shapes. The last shape painted will be painted on top of other shapes. Create an ArrayList of shapes to draw and then the paintComponent() method iterates through the ArrayList to paint each shape.

Comment: @camickr the thing is Board is its own object and Stones are own object... how do I make them related and draw on the same component?

Comment: Board is a panel. You override the paintComponent() method of the Board to paint the stones as described above. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028090/get-width-and-height-of-jpanel-outside-of-the-class/54028681#54028681 for an example.

Comment: ok will try this and check that link out.. thank you! @camickr

Comment: @camickr i updated my code but i am getting the same output... just the board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) writes in comments, the normal way to do this is to have the board-component paint the things that are in it.

In programs that have a graphical user interface (and also in others), you should generally separate your painting code (the **view**) from your knowing-what-to-paint code (the **model**). This idea is called [Model-View-Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Implementing MVC here would mean that your `Board` class should either know what to paint, or how to paint it, but not both. I propose having a

- `BoardPainter extends JPanel`, the view: knows how to paint things itself, has a `StonePainter` (which also extends `JPanel`) for each of the locations where stones can go. It does *not* keep information on what to paint where; instead, it asks this information from a `MancalaState` every time it needs it. When the game is further along, you will also generate moves here: click on source, click on destination,
- `MancalaState` would be the model, which knows how many stones are in each place, who is supposed to move, decides when the game is over, and so on. If you implement a `toString()` here, you can easily test that the whole game works correctly regardless of how it is painted.

To place the pots (`StonePainter`s) in their correct places in the `BoardPainter`, you can either work with an existing `LayoutManager` (even nesting JPanels), write your own `LayoutManager`, or directly not use a `StonePainter` and draw them directly from your `BoardPainter` at their correct locations. The easiest alternative, from my point of view, would be the the 1st:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Demo {

    /** paints a full board */
    public static class BoardPainter extends JPanel {
        private ArrayList<PotPainter> pots = new ArrayList<>();
        private java.util.List<Integer> mancalaBoard;  // <-- this would be an actual class

        public BoardPainter(java.util.List<Integer> mancalaBoard) {
            this.mancalaBoard = mancalaBoard;
            
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            
            // a 2x6 grid in the center
            JPanel center = new JPanel();
            center.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 6));
            for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
                PotPainter p = new PotPainter();
                pots.add(p);
                center.add(p);
            }
            add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // one side
            PotPainter east = new PotPainter();
            pots.add(east);            
            add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
            east.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 0));

            // the other side
            PotPainter west = new PotPainter();
            pots.add(west);            
            add(west, BorderLayout.WEST);
            west.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 0));            
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            for (int i=0; i<mancalaBoard.size(); i++) {
                pots.get(i).setStones(mancalaBoard.get(i));
            }
            super.paint(g);
        }
    }

    /** paints a pot */
    public static class PotPainter extends JPanel {
        private static final int MARGIN = 2;
        private static final int STONE_SIZE = 10;
        private int stones = 0;

        public void setStones(int stones) {
            this.stones = stones;
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawOval(MARGIN, MARGIN, getWidth()-MARGIN*2, getHeight()-MARGIN*2);
            Random r = new Random();
            int d = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2;
            Point center = new Point(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
            for (int i=0; i<stones; i++) {
                g.drawOval(center.x + r.nextInt(d) - d/2, center.y + r.nextInt(d) - d/2, 
                    STONE_SIZE, STONE_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String ...args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame jf = new JFrame("demo");
            jf.add(new BoardPainter(new ArrayList<>(
                Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 4, 2))));
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jf.setSize(800, 300);
            jf.setVisible(true);    
        });
    }
}
```

Sample output:

[image: Sample output]