# JComponents not showing on top of custom JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

Hello I am currently making a small game in java, and I am running into problems trying to making the gamepanel. I am using a JPanel as the basis and JPanel to the top to put in a HUD, and a gamepanel for the playable protion of the game. I can add the two panels the HUD and gamepanel fine. However the objects which are JComponents will not show up at all. I know they are created I'm not sure how to make them visible though.

Here are my classes:
This is my window class that holds the panels:

```
public class Window extends JFrame  {

public static final int ScreenWidth = 1000;
public static final int ScreenHeight = 700;
public static JFrame frame;
private StatesHandler statesHandler;
public Window(JFrame frame) throws IOException {
    this.frame = frame;
    this.statesHandler = new StatesHandler();
    displaywindow();
}



public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
}

public void displaywindow() {
    this.frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight));
    this.frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight));
    this.frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(ScreenWidth,ScreenHeight));
    this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.frame.setResizable(false);
    this.frame.setBackground(Color.pink);
    this.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.frame.pack();
    this.frame.setVisible(true);

}

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return this.frame;
}
```

This is this the level class:
it holds the hud and the gamepanel
private Window win;

```
Level(Window win) {
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gw,gh));
    this.win = win;
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.requestFocus();
    Hud hud = new Hud();
    getwinframe().getContentPane().add(hud);
    getwinframe().getContentPane().validate();
    gamepanel gmp = new gamepanel();
    getwinframe().getContentPane().add(gmp);
    getwinframe().getContentPane().revalidate();
    Ball ball = new Ball(600, 200, 3, 3);
    System.out.println(this);
    gmp.add(ball);
    gmp.revalidate();
    
}
```

Here is the Ball which I am trying to add to gamepanel

```
public Ball(int xpos, int ypos,int vx, int vy) {
    this.xpos =xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.vx = vx;
    this.vy = vy;
    this.collsionbox = new Rectangle(xpos, ypos, bwidth, bheight);

}
```

This is the gamepanel which I'm trying to add the ball to

```
 public gamepanel(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Window.ScreenWidth, Window.ScreenHeight -Window.ScreenHeight/6));
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    System.out.println(Window.ScreenWidth +"  " + Window.ScreenHeight/6);
    this.setBackground(Color.pink);
    Ball ball2 = new Ball(500, 100, 3, 3);
    
    System.out.println(ball2);
    add(ball2);
    validate();
}
```

Comment: 1) Don't override paint() on your JFrame. 2) Class names should start with an upper case character. Some are correct. Others are not. Be consistent! 3) For making a game you can do custom painting instead of trying to use real components. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028090/get-width-and-height-of-jpanel-outside-of-the-class/54028681#54028681 for an example of custom painting of multiple "ball" objects.

Comment: [Edit] to add a [mre] we can run and look at closely.