# Java how to have 2 components without layout?

Tags: java, swing, components

I have my Java project (link down there) and i want to add two custom components. I have tried adding them to panels, adding them to panels with layout, but nothing worked. I don't want layouts, since I am placing my components in special positions, which you can see in code. So here's code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Screen extends JFrame
{
public Cube cube;
public Cube cube2;

public Boolean running = true;

public Screen()
{
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    cube = new Cube(75, 75, 50, 50);
    cube2 = new Cube(10,950,1900,50,50);

    //setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    panel.add(cube);
    panel.add(cube2);

    getContentPane().add(panel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    Thread main = new MainThread();

    main.run();
}   

void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    cube.paint(g);
    cube2.paint(g);
}

public float Gravity = .00000000000881f;

public void Gravity()
{
    cube.AddVelocity(0f,Gravity);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Screen();
}

class MainThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        try{
            sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Starting");
        while(running){
            //System.out.println("cube: " + cube.x + "," + cube.y);
            //System.out.println("cube2: " + cube2.x + "," + cube2.y);
            cube.UpdateMethod();
            Gravity();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
}

public class Cube extends JComponent {
float x, y, sizex, sizey, shift;
    
public Cube(int x, int y, int size, int shift) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sizex = size;
        this.sizey = size;
        this.shift = shift;
    }

public Cube(int x, int y, int sx, int sy, int shift) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.sizex = sx;
    this.sizey = sy;
    this.shift = shift;
}


Vector2 Velocity = new Vector2(0,0);

public void AddVelocity(float a, float b)
    {
        Velocity.x += a;
        Velocity.y += b;
    }

public void MoveBy(Float x, float y)
    {
        this.x+=x;
        this.y+=y;
        
        repaint();
    }

public void UpdateMethod()
{
    MoveBy(Velocity.GetX(), Velocity.GetY());

        
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int nx = (int) x;
        int ny = (int) y;

        int nsx = (int) sizex;
        int nsy = (int) sizey;
        g.drawRect(nx, ny, nsx, nsy);
    }


Boolean CheckCollision(Cube other)
{
    if(x < other.x + other.sizex &&
    x + sizex > other.x &&
    y < other.y + other.sizey &&
    sizey + sizey > other.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}

class Vector2
{
public float x,y;

public Vector2(int a, int b)
{
    x=a;
    y=b;
}

public float GetX()
{
    return x;
}

public float GetY()
{
    return y;
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Method names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) Use a Swing Timer for animation. 3) Components will only be painted if they have a size and location. The default size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. 4) Generally it is better to keep an ArrayLIst of shapes to paint and then have your panel paint iterate through the list to paint all the shapes. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028090/get-width-and-height-of-jpanel-outside-of-the-class/54028681#54028681 for an example that implements all the above suggestions.

Comment: Thanks, i also forgot to say that only last component that i add cube2 in this case is shown

Comment: *only last component that i add cube2 in this case is shown* - you set the layout manager to a BorderLayout. Only one component can be added to the CENTER, so only the last one added is given a size/location. When you need animation you need to use a null layout or better yet don't use components as has already been suggested.

Comment: `Cube` should not `extends JComponent`. When you are clear on that & committed to going in a different direction, let me know, and I'll put more time into (commenting or) answering.

Comment: Cube needs to extends JComponent, since it has paint() method, which is called when cube object is added to frame. Also thank's for help

Comment: A POJO `Cube` could implement a `draw(Graphics)` method that is explicitly called within the `paintComponent(Graphics)`(1) method of the `JComponent` or (more commonly) `JPanel` that is painting it. 1) For any `JComponent`, override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` method rather than the `paint(Graphics)` method.