# How to call the paintComponent method from a loop?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to draw graphics by calling the class `Habitat` in the code below.
I am calling it from a loop.
I am guessing this isn't the best way to do it as is it making multiple instances of the same name?
Sorry, new to Java so hope this makes sense.

```java
public Habitat (int c,int w,int h,int[][] s) {
    habitatWidth = w;
    habitatHeight = h;
    plantSize = s;
    counter = c;
    p1 = new Plants(10,10,40,s);
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    RenderingHints rh = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                                           RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHints(rh);

    //sets background color
    Rectangle2D.Double r = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, habitatWidth, habitatHeight);
    g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));

    // fill the shape
    g2d.fill(r);

    //draw the plant p1
    p1.drawPlants(g2d);
}
```

Comment: You don't call the `paintComponent` method at all.  You call `repaint`, which calls the `paintComponent` method.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: Don't call repaint() from a loop. If you need animation, you should be using a Swing Timer. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872

Comment: For checking the code, always add `@Override` before overriding _and implementing_ methods.