# Can't Draw/Add image to the List in java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

All code which is linked to ArrayList/List i have:

```
public void draw(Graphics2D gImages) {
    List missiles = aiShooter.getMissiles();

    if(keyH.shooting) {
        for(int i = 0; i < missiles.size(); i++) {
            Missile mis = (Missile) missiles.get(i);
            System.out.println("Shot");
            aiShooter.fire();
            mis.move();
            gImages.fillRect(mis.X, mis.Y, mis.Width, mis.Height);
        }
    }
    gImages.fillRect(X2, Y2, Width, Height);
    gImages.fillRect(X, Y, Width, Height);
}
```

```
package testGames2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AIShooter {

    public static int X = 200;
    public static int Y = 50;
    public static int Width = 10;
    public static int Height = 3;
    List<Missile> missiles new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Missile> getMissiles() {
        return missiles;
    }

    public void fire() {
        missiles.add(new Missile(Missile.X, Missile.Y, Missile.Width, Missile.Height));
    }
}
```

```
package testGames2;

public class Missile {

    public static int X = AIShooter.X;
    public static int Y = AIShooter.Y;
    public static int Width = 10;
    public static int Height = 3;

    public Missile(int X, int Y, int Width, int Height) {
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
        this.Width = Width;
        this.Height = Height;
    }

    public void move() {
        X += 10;
    }

}
```

I either Can't add Missile to List, or rectangle(Missile) doesn't drawing.
I tried several methods, but none of them worked.
If more code is needed, just tell me.
Any help is truly Appreciated!

Comment: JOGL (OGL) is a much better platform for game development

Comment: I'm interested only in learning Java, Thanks

Comment: You need to use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872 for an example to get you started.

Comment: Sorry, but how it will help me? Could you explain this?

Comment: You haven't posted any code that *calls* `draw()`. Btw, I don't think it's a good idea to have a method called `fire` that simply adds an element to a `List`

Comment: If you need code that calls that draw method, i'm going to post it. And what about fire method? (What should i do instead?)

Comment: *how it will help me?* - it shows you how to iterate through an ArrayList and paint objects moving on the panel. The point if for you to understand how that code works and then implement changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to fire should add the new `Missile` created to the missiles `ArrayList`. Why do you think it isn't being added?

Also, for drawing your missiles, you need to set your `Graphics2D` context with something like `setColor(someColor)` before your call to `fillRect`. Perhaps that context was set prior to the call to `draw()`?

Comment: *You need to set your Graphics2D context with something like setColor(someColor) before your call to fillRect.* What would be wrong with the default? *Perhaps that context was set prior to the call to draw()?* Which call? - none is shown