# java swing make a smooth transition animation for resizing Jframe height

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I'm working on a small GUI application and part of this application I intend to resize the JFrame after I press a button. I managed to resize the JFrame, but I wanted to create a smooth animation for the opening and closing of this JFrame. I'm not sure where and how to start. I know that I can imagine pressing the button which will run a thread/method and resize the JFrame. I'll try give as much detail as possible through some screenshots.

[Here is a before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzb4Y.png) - before JFrame resize

[and here is a after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr80r.png) - after JFrame resize

Code for current resize for JFrame

```java
changeBottomFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(!heightIncreased[0]){
            try{
                frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()+80);
                if(frame.getHeight()==450){
                    frame.add(bottomFrame, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
                    changeBottomFrame.setText("∨");
                    heightIncreased[0] =true;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

        } else if (heightIncreased[0]) {
            try {
                frame.setSize(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight() - 80);
                if(frame.getHeight()==370) {
                    frame.remove(bottomFrame);
                    changeBottomFrame.setText("∧");
                    heightIncreased[0] = false;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        {}
    }
});
```

In the screenshots, I added a JPanel to *highlight* the area amount added, and shown in the code you can see `frame.add(bottomFrame)` for clarification.

I am new to Java coding and I've made smooth animation transitions in Python GUIs, but I'm not experienced with Java Swing.

Comment: Screenshots of your frame are fine, but don't post screenshots of your code. Actually copy and paste your code into the question.

Comment: *I can imagine pressing the button which will run a thread/method and resize the JFrame.* - Actually you would use a Swing Timer for animation. You would adjust the frame location/size every time the timer fires. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872 for an example of animation. *I'm not experienced with Java swing* Also check out [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for Timer basics and keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.

Comment: okay okay, sorry about the code screenshots, I will edit it now, and also thank you for the idea of a swing timer, I will look into it. I appreciate it.

Comment: @jes Yes, a Swing Timer is wise for creating a smooth effect. You should also look into `Window::addWindowStateListener` -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowStateListener(java.awt.event.WindowStateListener) -- which gives you `WindowStateListener::windowStateChanged` -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowStateListener.html -- which gives you the states of `WindowEvent` -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowEvent.html#field-summary

Comment: And in case it's not clear, `WindowEvent` extends `ComponentEvent`, which has https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#COMPONENT_RESIZED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a runnable demo which demonstrates how this could be done. The methods using to animate the opening, extending, and closing of the JFrame window are located within the **AnimateForm** class named `animateForm()` and `animateFormClose()`. The `animateForm()` method makes use of a Swing Timer and the `animateFormClose()` method animates the closing of the form utilizing a `while` loop.

[image]

Keep in mind, this is just a simple demo.

---

**The SwingFormAnimationDemo Class:**

```
public class SwingFormAnimationDemo {

    private javax.swing.JFrame frame;
    private javax.swing.JPanel rootPanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton resizeButton;

    private int desiredFormWidth = 500;
    private int desiredFormHeight = 300;
    private int widthIncrement = 10;
    private int heightIncrement = 10;
    private int speed = 5;
    private int initialDelay = 300;

    private int desiredFormExtentionWidthAmount = 0;
    private int desiredFormExtentionHeightAmount = 100;
    private int extensionWidthIncrement = 3;
    private int extensionHeightIncrement = 3;
    private int extentionSpeed = 10;
    private int extensionInitialDelay = 300;

    private AnimateForm animate;

    public SwingFormAnimationDemo() {
        initForm();
        animate = new AnimateForm();
        animate.animateForm(frame, desiredFormWidth, desiredFormHeight,
                widthIncrement, heightIncrement, speed, initialDelay);

        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowListener() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                animate.animateFormClose(frame);
                if (AnimateForm.animateFormTimer.isRunning()) {
                    AnimateForm.animateFormTimer.stop();
                }
                frame.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }
        });
        
        resizeButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
            if (resizeButton.getText().equals("Longer Form")) {
                animate.animateForm(frame, frame.getWidth() + desiredFormExtentionWidthAmount,
                        frame.getHeight() + desiredFormExtentionHeightAmount,
                        extensionWidthIncrement, extensionHeightIncrement,
                        extentionSpeed, extensionInitialDelay);
                resizeButton.setText("Shorter Form");
            }
            else {
                animate.animateForm(frame, frame.getWidth() - desiredFormExtentionWidthAmount,
                        frame.getHeight() - desiredFormExtentionHeightAmount,
                        extensionWidthIncrement, extensionHeightIncrement,
                        extentionSpeed, extensionInitialDelay);
                resizeButton.setText("Longer Form");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingFormAnimationDemo().startApp(args);
    }

    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        });

    }

    private void initForm() {
        frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Swing Form Animation Demo");
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(0, 0));
        
        rootPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        resizeButton = new javax.swing.JButton("Longer Form");
        rootPanel.add(resizeButton);

        javax.swing.JTable table = new javax.swing.JTable(17, 3);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
        table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
        table.setGridColor(java.awt.Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        javax.swing.JScrollPane sp = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(table);
        sp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 300));
        rootPanel.add(sp);

        frame.setContentPane(rootPanel);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

---

**The AnimateForm Class:**

```
public class AnimateForm {

    public static javax.swing.Timer animateFormTimer;

    public void animateForm(javax.swing.JFrame suppliedFrame, int width, int height,
            int widthIncrement, int heightIncrement, int speed, int initialDelay) {
        animateFormTimer = new javax.swing.Timer(speed, (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) -> {
            boolean widthRetraction = width < suppliedFrame.getWidth();
            boolean heightRetraction = height < suppliedFrame.getHeight();

            // Form animation...
            if (width > suppliedFrame.getWidth()) {
                suppliedFrame.setSize(suppliedFrame.getWidth() + widthIncrement,
                        suppliedFrame.getHeight());
            }
            else if (width < suppliedFrame.getWidth()) {
                suppliedFrame.setSize(suppliedFrame.getWidth() - widthIncrement,
                        suppliedFrame.getHeight());
            }
            else {
                suppliedFrame.setSize(width, suppliedFrame.getHeight());
            }

            if (height > suppliedFrame.getHeight()) {
                suppliedFrame.setSize(suppliedFrame.getWidth(),
                        suppliedFrame.getHeight() + heightIncrement);
            }
            else if (height < suppliedFrame.getHeight()) {
                suppliedFrame.setSize(suppliedFrame.getWidth(),
                        suppliedFrame.getHeight() - heightIncrement);
            }
            else {
                suppliedFrame.setSize(suppliedFrame.getWidth(), height);
            }

            if ((widthRetraction ? suppliedFrame.getWidth() <= width : suppliedFrame.getWidth() >= width)
                    && (heightRetraction ? suppliedFrame.getHeight() <= height : suppliedFrame.getHeight() >= height)) {
                animateFormTimer.stop();
            }
        });
        animateFormTimer.setInitialDelay(initialDelay);
        animateFormTimer.start();
    }

    public void animateFormClose(javax.swing.JFrame frame) {
        while (frame.getWidth() > 140 || frame.getHeight() > 40) {
            frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() - 1, frame.getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh cool. I would have done this with a WindowStateListener instead, but this works too.

Comment: yes this one worked well for me. I implemented a few extra variables and combined it with my code and managed to get it to work. Thank you so much
-sorry i would give a vote up but I don't have enough reputation haha