# How can I determine the "time" of contact between a circle and a wall?

Tags: java, swing, geometry, simulation

I'm a relatively new programmer, and I'm trying to write a simple simulation in Java for personal enrichment using the swing library. One thing I'm struggling with is updating my entities (a ball in this case) to their points of contact with a wall. Currently, I detect collisions a step before they happen so that I can bounce them off of walls. My simulation's update function is as follows, as well as my `Entity`'s update functions (I know it's VERY messy; I plan on cleaning it up once it's working):

```
public void update()
{
    // Iterate through each entity in the list
    for (Entity entity : entities)
    {
        // Flag to determine if the entity has bounced off a wall
        boolean bounced = false;

        // Iterate through each wall in the list
        for (Wall wall : walls)
        {
            // Get the future position of the entity
            float[] nextPos = entity.getFuture();

            // Check if the entity is a Ball
            if (entity instanceof Ball)
            {
                // Create a vector representing the wall
                Vector wallVector = new Vector(wall.p2.x, wall.p2.y).vsubtract(new Vector(wall.p1.x, wall.p1.y));

                // Calculate vectors from the ball's center to the wall
                Vector ballPosToWall = new Vector(((Ball) entity).centerx, ((Ball) entity).centery).vsubtract(new Vector(wall.p1.x, wall.p1.y));
                Vector nextPosToWall = new Vector(nextPos[0], nextPos[1]).vsubtract(new Vector(wall.p1.x, wall.p1.y));

                // Calculate interpolation values for the current and next positions
                float ballInterp = ballPosToWall.dot(wallVector) / wallVector.getLengthSquared();
                float nextInterp = nextPosToWall.dot(wallVector) / wallVector.getLengthSquared();

                // Clamp interpolation values to the range [0, 1]
                ballInterp = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, ballInterp));
                nextInterp = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, nextInterp));

                // Calculate points on the wall corresponding to the ball's current and next positions
                Vector ballPoint = wallVector.scale(ballInterp).vadd(new Vector(wall.p1.x, wall.p1.y));
                Vector nextPoint = wallVector.scale(nextInterp).vadd(new Vector(wall.p1.x, wall.p1.y));

                // Calculate distances from the ball to the wall at the current and next positions
                float currentDistance = (float) Math.sqrt(((ballPoint.dx - ((Ball) entity).centerx) * (ballPoint.dx - ((Ball) entity).centerx)) 
                        + ((ballPoint.dy - ((Ball) entity).centery) * (ballPoint.dy - ((Ball) entity).centery)));

                float nextDistance = (float) Math.sqrt(((nextPoint.dx - nextPos[0]) * (nextPoint.dx - nextPos[0])) 
                        + ((nextPoint.dy - nextPos[1]) * (nextPoint.dy - nextPos[1])));

                // Check if the ball will collide with the wall in the next position
                if (nextDistance <= entity.width / 2)
                {
                    // Calculate the portion of the step before the collision and after the bounce
                    // float stepsToWall = ???
                    // float stepsAfterBounce = 1 - stepsToWall;

                    // Update the entity up to the collision point
                    // entity.update(stepsToWall);

                    // Reflect the entity's vector based on the wall's normal, simulating a bounce
                    entity.setVector(entity.getVector().reflect(wallVector.normalize()));

                    // Update the entity after the bounce
                    // entity.update(stepsAfterBounce);

                    // Set the bounce flag to true
                    bounced = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // If the entity did not bounce off of any walls, update it normally
        if (!bounced)
            entity.update();
    }
}
```

```
public void update()
{
    x += velocity.dx;
    y += velocity.dy;
}

public void update(float steps)
{
    x += velocity.dx * steps;
    y += velocity.dy * steps;
}
```

My `Wall` class simply houses two endpoints. I also wrote a custom `Vector` class (which houses a dx and dy value) to handle all of the vector calculations, which works as intended.

Everything (as far as I know) works, except I can't seem to find a calculation to get the `stepsToWall`. I've tried a number of things but I know I'm not in the right ballpark, and I'm not the greatest at math. I DO know that it should be a number between 0 and 1. Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, and yes, I'm aware the code needs cleaning :P. This is my first question, so sorry if I didn't provide adequate information. If anything else is wanted or needed I will provide it.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872 for one approach.

Comment: The AWT package has a [Rectangle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) class.  The `Rectangle` class has an `intersects` method that takes other rectangles.  Walls are flat rectangles.  The intersects method of a ball (circle) is simply less than or equal to the radius of the circle.  Keep track of the ball using polar coordinates and convert them to cartesian coordinates for drawing and intersect calculations.