# Optimizing moving JPanels in Java Swing program

Tags: java, swing, optimization, lag, frame-rate

I'm trying to run some performance tests for some game I'm planning to program with Java Swing as a warmup on Swing API. Simply put, the game is based on some multiple windows moving in accordance and showing different entities of the game. So for the performance test, I wrote the a code that just randomly puts JPanels on the screen and then moves/resizes them randomly while constantly changing their background color all with a constant FPS of 60.

The problem is that the FPS drops below 10 when showing 4 windows or more and I don't know what I'm doing wrong/can do to enhance performance. I've tried to avoid abusing repaint/paintComponent and use of Thread Sleeps but I don't know what else I can do to get better performance out of this. I'm looking forward to like 15 windows all moving and changing the contentPane all at 60 FPS and this actually seems reasonably possible to me but currently I'm stuck.

Any help/hint/source would be appreciated.

```
package org.example;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class Main {
    public static final int FPS = 60;
    public static final int HEIGHT = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
    public static final int WIDTH = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;
    public static final float ACCELERATION = 0.3F;
    public static final float SPEED = 0F;
    static int cnt=0;
    static JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        spawnInitialFrame();
        new Timer(500, e -> {
            if (cnt%10==0) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::spawnPanel);
            }
            cnt++;
        }){{setCoalesce(false);}}.start();
    }
    public static void spawnInitialFrame(){
        System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl", "true");
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    }
    public static void spawnPanel() {
        Random rng=new Random();
        JPanel panel=new JPanel(){{changeColor(this);}};
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(200,200));
        int destX=WIDTH/2+rng.nextInt(-500,500);
        int destY=HEIGHT/2+rng.nextInt(-500,500);
        panel.setLocation(destX,destY);
        frame.add(panel);

        AtomicReference<Timer> temp=new AtomicReference<>(){{set(null);}};
        new Timer(500,e -> {
            if (temp.get()!=null){temp.get().stop();}
            int a1=rng.nextInt(-100,100);
            int a2=rng.nextInt(-100,100);
            int a3=rng.nextInt(-20,20);
            int a4=rng.nextInt(-20,20);

            a1=(a1+panel.getLocation().x<0 | a1+panel.getLocation().x>WIDTH) ? -a1 : a1;
            a2=(a2+panel.getLocation().y<0 | a2+panel.getLocation().y>HEIGHT) ? -a2 : a2;
            a3=(a3+panel.getWidth()<=0) ? -a3 : a3;
            a4=(a4+panel.getHeight()<=0) ? -a4 : a4;
//                a3=0;a4=0;
//                a1=0;a2=0;
            Timer timer=smoothen(panel, a1, a2, a3, a4);
            timer.start();
            temp.set(timer);

        }).start();
    }
    public static void changeColor(JPanel panel){
        Random rng=new Random();
        new Timer(500, e -> {
            panel.setBackground(new Color(rng.nextInt(100,200),rng.nextInt(100,200),rng.nextInt(100,200),255));
        }){{setCoalesce(false);}}.start();
    }
    public static Timer smoothen(JPanel panel, int moveX,int moveY,int progW,int progH) {
        final int[] cntMoveX = {0};
        final int[] progMoveX = {0};
        final int[] cntMoveY = {0};
        final int[] progMoveY = {0};
        final int[] cntWidth = {0};
        final int[] progWidth = {0};
        final int[] cntHeight = {0};
        final int[] progHeight = {0};

        return new Timer(500/FPS,e -> {
            int x = panel.getLocation().x;
            int y = panel.getLocation().y;
            int h = panel.getHeight();
            int w = panel.getWidth();
            boolean changeLocation=false;
            boolean changeSize=false;

            if (abs(progMoveX[0]) < abs(moveX)) {
                int turnProg = (int) (Math.floor(cntMoveX[0] * ACCELERATION + SPEED) * sgn(moveX));
                progMoveX[0] += turnProg;
                cntMoveX[0]++;
                x += turnProg;
                changeLocation=true;
            }
            if (abs(progMoveY[0]) < abs(moveY)) {
                int turnProg = (int) (Math.floor(cntMoveY[0] * ACCELERATION + SPEED) * sgn(moveY));
                progMoveY[0] += turnProg;
                cntMoveY[0]++;
                y += turnProg;
                changeLocation=true;
            }
            if (abs(progWidth[0]) < abs(progW)) {
                int turnProg = (int) (Math.floor(cntWidth[0] * ACCELERATION + SPEED) * sgn(progW));
                progWidth[0] += turnProg;
                cntWidth[0]++;
                h += turnProg;
                changeSize=true;
            }
            if (abs(progHeight[0]) < abs(progH)) {
                int turnProg = (int) (Math.floor(cntHeight[0] * ACCELERATION + SPEED) * sgn(progH));
                progHeight[0] += turnProg;
                cntHeight[0]++;
                w += turnProg;
                changeSize=true;
            }
            if (changeLocation) panel.setLocation(x, y);
            if (changeSize) panel.setSize(w, h);
        }){{setCoalesce(true);}};
    }
    public static int abs(int a) {
        return (a <= 0) ? -a : a;
    }
    public static int sgn(int a) {
        return (a <= 0) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that might improve efficiency would be to consider avoiding moving components such as JPanels, which are heavier weight than an image sprite. What is the rationale for requiring that the moving entities must be a Swing component?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The design of the game is quite complicated but I can almost assure you that there is no other way than using a JComponent. If you need a simple explanation, the game has several (moving) windows and the bullets are bounded to the boundaries of the windows, unless two windows overlap. So you actually do need some JComponents to move accordingly.

Comment: a `while(true)` loop is never a good idea. A Swing Timer should be used for animation.

Comment: "the game has several (moving) windows and the bullets are bounded to the boundaries of the windows, unless two windows overlap."  This can be done with rectangular sprites.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the comment. Previously I did try to avoid this but it got to some unexpected GUI behavior. However I managed to fix it and now my program has slightly better performance, capping at 6,7 JPanels running at 60 FPS but I'm still far from being convinced that this is actually the limit. Thanks again for your comment

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I've read these tutorials before yet I don't see clearly how it is possible to do this using rectangular sprites. For a precise reference, this is the game I'm trying to make: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEV_4DTRhFM

Comment: You do this using "shapes". A shape is very flexible. It could be rectangular or circular for example. Or, you can even combine multiple shapes into one. Typically you would create an ArrayList of Shapes to paint. Then the paintComponent() method iterates through all the shapes. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872 for a basic example of this approach. Add a many balls as you want.

Comment: @camickr I'll try this out but I don't think this would lead to better performance because of the huge load of "paint" methods that are going to be called. On the other hand it seems quite unnatural and irritating to me to use Shapes when naturally I must use something that acts like a container.